# Conditional format formula for row colour based on date, but to ignore if other cell contains certain text

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a Google sheet that I want to apply conditional formatting, the formula I have now doesn't seem to work as it still highlights rows that I want to ignore.

I have about 15 columns of data but only want to focus on columns B,C,D
B  Order status
C Date ordered
D Ship by date

Originally, I was trying to only highlight rows that are overdue.
So that if the date in D cell is today onward it would make the row red, but, to ignore this rule if the status in B cell is 'fulfilled'.

This formula ( I had someone do for me ) kept giving random results
=IF(AND($D1 > TODAY(),$B1 <> "FULFILLED"),TRUE,FALSE)

I would also like to add 2 other conditions to colour grade rows.

-To mark the rows as green from order date up to 3 days before the due date

-To mark the rows as orange 3 days before and up until the due date.

So that orders that have not been fulfilled will go from green to orange to red.

If unclear, I can provide more information.

Comment: Formula seems fine. May be your apply ranges is not correct. Share a sample sheet here so that we can check it.

Comment: Ok, I've just created a sheet with some of the input from my original. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k2RmX5KRDQqVDmDlPvhGVKKIRDz_4SAK_sbmuKDNmTI/edit?usp=sharing, it seems everything that is not 'fulfilled get highlighted even if it's not due yet

Comment: I think it is working as intended. `Row 2` is not fulfilled and not due, such that it is not highlighted. Could be you specific what combinations give an undesired result?

Comment: Row 2, I changed it for the 3rd December to match the 'TODAY' date, with status of 'submitted' which should highlight the row in red - but it doesn't. The following rows (4-7) are red, but they are nowhere near their due date. The rows should only highlight if the due date in D column is today or earlier and doesn't have a fulfilled status. I've also added headers and changed the range to not include them, but now a 'fulfilled order gets highlighted. Not sure what I've done wrong...

Comment: Ok, it's working now, I flipped the formula around to =IF(AND($B2 <> "FULFILLED",$D2 <TODAY()),TRUE,FALSE) for some reason it works how it should, I can create modifications from here. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

#### WORKING ANSWER:

`=IF(AND($B2 <> "FULFILLED",$D2 <TODAY()),TRUE,FALSE)`

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70196177/conditional-format-formula-for-row-colour-based-on-date-but-to-ignore-if-other#comment124113127_70196177)